# PyCharm professional edition cannot support Django

Tags: django, pycharm

I have PyCharm professional edition, and I have been trying to PyCharm and Django. However, it seems that I could not enable Django support in PyCharm. As shown in the following figure, when I try to enable Django support in the PyCharm setting, there is nothing shown for Django.

Can anyone help me identify the issue?

[image]

Comment: I am using Mac OS 10.12

Comment: You can try `File->Invalidate Caches / Restart`.

Comment: @illagrenan it doesn't help.

Comment: Which version of PyCharm are you using?

Comment: 2017.1   I used 2016.3 with the same issue. @nik_m

Answer (score 0):

That's because you **haven't** created a project yet. You get this screen because you're still in the step before creating a project.

1. Create a new project
2. Select Django on the left column
3. Enter a name for your project
4. Select (or create on the fly) a virtualenv
5. Click the `Create` button

Now, **after** project has been created, you can go to `Languages & Frameworks => Django` and then enable the `Django support` by selecting your project root directory and your `settings.py` file.

Comment: Well, this is what is shown after I have created a Django project... So creating a project does not seem to work.

Comment: You have Django installed? Have you enabled any virtualenv that has Django installed?

Comment: Yes, I have Django installed.